# Android app doesn't explain why image upload fails

Tags: bug, android-app, images

I've been trying to pay an image on a question which is a photo on my phone. I cropped it so it's small in size and pixels but it keeps failing and I'm not told why, I just get an error report.

It would be great if it told me what changes are needed, assuming there isn't simply a server issue.

Comment: It's not you, it's the app. The app is broken. Please use a browser app on your phone to browse to Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.